# Current Routing to Many Connectors

Tags: current, routing

I have a board that is meant for power distribution. It takes in +24V through a 6x2 Wire-to-Board connector rated for 23A per contact and routes it to 22 other 2x2 SMD Wire-to-Board connectors which are rated for 8A per contact, but realistically I will be drawing 6A per connector at most. So, I need to plan for a worst-case scenario in which 22 connectors are each drawing 6A at once.

At the moment I have the input connector in the middle of one edge of the board (100x220mm rectangular board) and then four rows of five connectors down the length of the board, with an extra in the two nearest corners. I was hoping to route the +24V traces down each row and just split off to each connector, but with a 1oz copper pour I would need >35mm thick copper traces to account for 30A of current and I only have space for 19mm thick traces, so that is a no go.

So now I've basically just covered the entire top layer with a +24V copper pour, and the bottom layer with a GND pour, and each of the ground pins just has a small polygon around it with enough vias for 6A (plus extra) to route down to the GND layer. *So*, my question is: does this amount of current flowing through the entire top layer of the board and going to so many places cause any issues? Do I need to route it more path-like, and likely step up to a 2oz copper weight? [image: Screenshot of the board as it currently stands.]

Comment: 2oz copper wouldn't hurt, maybe even 3oz if your fab supports it. (PCBway, for instance, will quite happily go up to *13oz* if you're willing to pay for it). If you can add more layers and use a couple layers in parallel, that's also an option. Or give up on doing this on a PCB altogether and just do it on a DIN rail with big terminal blocks and thick wires.

Comment: @Hearth DIN rail is not a bad idea. And I appreciate your answer but 2oz is a big cost jump as is more layers, especially since these are going to be a very low quantity order, so I'm more curious about the feasibility of this full pour design and less about the ways I can overengineer it if that makes sense.

Comment: Check options at other fabs. PCBway and JLCPCB are both pretty cheap even with four layers (though six and up gets pricy fast).